# Using Promises with Mongoose Model Statics

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I have a piece of code which finds the record with the highest value for a Numeric field, 'ordinal':

```
Job.find({}).sort({'ordinal': -1}).limit(1).then(maxOrd => {
    console.log(`Found MaxOrd: ${maxOrd}`);
});
```

This works fine.  Now I'd like to make this a static method of the `Job` schema.  As so I tried:

```
JobSchema.statics.findMaxOrdinal = function(callback) {
    Job.find({}, callback).sort({'ordinal': -1}).limit(1);

};
```

...and:

```
Job.findMaxOrdinal().then(maxOrd => {
    console.log(`Found Max Ord using Promise: ${maxOrd}`);
});
```

But this isn't working, and crashes with a very unhelpful stack trace.

How do I write my static so that I can use it with a Promise?

Comment: According to the docs: `Mongoose queries are not promises. However, they do have a .then() function for yield and async/await. If you need a fully-fledged promise, use the .exec() function.`

Comment: Aren't you just missing a `return` statement? I'm not sure what you expect to happen with your callback argument. Also, @funcoding - that statement could be argued against, since thanks to multiple implementing libraries, the (overly broad, simplistic) definition for promises is "An object that has a .then() function on it for callbacks".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just return mongoose query like this:

```
JobSchema.statics.findMaxOrdinal = function() {
    return Job.find({}).sort({'ordinal': -1}).limit(1);
};
```

Comment: That's great, thanks.  I was making it more complicated than it is.

This function returns an array with 1 element.  Is there a way to return just the single element instead of an array?  Or even just return the `ordinal` value itself?

Comment: Answered my own question:  `return Job.find({}).sort({'ordinal': -1}).limit(1).then(recs => recs[0].ordinal);`  And later:  `Job.findMaxOrdinal().then(maxOrd => console.log(maxOrd) );`